# What's the purpose (and any extra effect) of calling function when declaring export?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, module, export

Simple export ends with the function/variable/class declaration such as
`export default hello`

Imagining that `hello` is a function in a `hello` module. What is the the difference between calling `export default hello()` within the module that is being exported and calling `hello()` in the module that imports `import hello from "./hello"`?

Seems like there is no difference apart from the fact that second option requires to initilise (call) function within the module that imports `hello`.

// hello.js

```
function hello () {
  console.log("hello")
 }

// 1st option function declaration
export default hello

// 2nd option - run function on export
export default hello()
```

// index.js

```
import hello from "./hello";

// 1st option initialise (calling)
hello();

// 2nd option - no calling needed
```

Searched throughout the web, but can't find what are the possible side effects or which of these is better way of handling module that contains and exports a function.

Comment: This entirely depends on what your function actually does and whether it's something designed to be called many times or not. If the function is a random utility, it makes no sense to call it up front. There is no right or wrong answer to this for the general case.

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful. Would you say, that 2nd option is also a correct way of doing an export (depending on use case of course)??

Comment: That depends if the thing your users want to import is the function, or whatever value the function returns. If your file did `function getHello(){ return hello; } export default getHello()` it'd be identical to `export default hello;`. The value being exported is what matters, not where the value comes from.

Answer (score 0):

If you import the function from two different modules:

```
  // A
 import hello from "./hello";
 hello();

 //B
 import hello from "./hello";
 hello();
```

the function gets called twice. If you export the functions result, the function will definetly only run once.

That said it makes little sense to have a function at all in the second case as this:

```
 function hello () {
  console.log("hello");
  return "something";
 }

 export default hello();
```

equals:

```
 console.log("hello");
 export default "something";
```

Comment: Sorry, I dont get it. Why would you import twice same function ?  and there is no difference between A and B

Comment: So, which one is better?